# A function to load xts data into R

Tags: r, function, load, xts

I'm trying to write a function that will load some xts data into **R**, and sort them by the date/time I specify. Maybe I'm trying a too simplistic method, but here is my code:

```
load.data <- function (x, time1, time2) #x is going to be the actual file name
{
    vector = get(load("C:/Users/username/Desktop/x"))
    sortvector = vector['time1/time2/']
    return (sortvector)
}
```

And when I execute it, I get the message:

```
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/x', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

So, how can I make it so that my function will actually search for the file name, rather than actual generic 'x'? I hope I was clear, and I would certainly appreciate any help greatly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want `sortvector` to be.  Look at `?'[.xts'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `paste` or `paste0`

```
load.data <- function (x, time1, time2) #x is going to be the actual file name
{
    vector = get(load(paste0("C:/Users/username/Desktop/", x)))
    sortvector = vector[paste(time1, time2, sep='/')]
    return(sortvector)
}
```

Also, look at `?FinancialInstrument:::saveSymbols.days` and `?FinancialInstrument:::getSymbols.FI`, or look at the code for those functions for examples of saving and loading `xts` objects

**Edit**

Here's an example

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- xts(cumsum(rnorm(100)), as.POSIXct("2012-05-23") + 1:100*60*60*6)
tmpdir <- tempdir()
save(dat, file=file.path(tmpdir, "dat.RData"))
rm('dat') 

time1 <- "2012-05-24 10:00:00"
time2 <- "2012-05-25 11:00:00"
vector = get(load(paste(tmpdir, "dat.RData", sep="/")))
sortvector = vector[paste(time1, time2, sep='/')]
sortvector
#                         [,1]
#2012-05-24 12:00:00 -2.044404
#2012-05-24 18:00:00 -2.829308
#2012-05-25 00:00:00 -4.497250
#2012-05-25 06:00:00 -4.877477
```

Comment: Thanky you very much for the help! I feel like this is the way to go, but there is still something I'm missing because now I'm getting NA. Regarding your question, I want sortvector to be a vector that only extracts data from 'time1' to 'time2' in that xts. I'll just specify time1 and time2 as my inputs

Comment: for example, vector['2012.05.24 10:00:00/2012.05.25 11:00:00']

Comment: I think you mean '2012-05-24 10:00:00/2012-05-25 11:00:00']

Comment: Great! If that answers your question, please check the check mark next to my answer to indicate to others that your issue has been solved.  Thanks.

Comment: I will do that for sure. Also, if you have time and if I'm not getting ahead of myself, could you possibly know how I can modify my function so that I can look at same times from different days? For example, let's say I want to look at data between 11:00 and 12:00 from day 5/25 to 5/30? I guess I can do them all separately and then rbind them, but to be able to incorporate this as an input to my function would be amazing. If you think that's too much of a hassle, once again, thank you very much.

Comment: 'T11:00/T12:00' means 11 to 12 for all days.